# What Demons/Devils have trident attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, tomb-of-annihilation

I'm trying to look up an old item my character had pilfered off some demon or devil that involved an 'Infernal Trident' that had special properties. When an attack lands, it causes the target to make a CON save or become infernally wounded. I wish I had my old sheet, would anyone have insight on what this may be? We ran into it during the Tomb of Annihilation.

Comment: Ive added the [dnd-5e] tag since you mentioned the 5e adventure *Tomb of Annihilation*.

Comment: That said, welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment, and peruse the [help] for more details about the site.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov The 5e adventure is a rehash of an older adventure from 1e or 2e days, I'm not sure. Are you sure we're talking ablut the 5e one?

Comment: @Zachiel Did the old one have Infernal Wounds and constitution saving throws?

Comment: Some devils had things that wounded in weird hard to heal ways and they might have had that name in 2e but you're right, it would have been saves versus death or petrification like in Baldur's Gate pre-3e. Good logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You’re likely thinking of either a bearded or a horned devil.

The bearded and horned devils are [the only monsters with an “infernal wound” mechanic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=Infernal%20wound). The horned devil in particular appears to carry a bident. However, it should be noted that there is no official player-facing magic item that has that ability, so it is quite likely a homebrew magic item the DM created as a reward for defeating the devil(s) or something like that. Both of these devils are featured at least once in *Tomb of Annihilation*.

#### Or maybe a Nycaloth?

The [nycaloth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17125-nycaloth) has a similar mechanic called a “fiendish wound” that works essentially the same way. I mention this guy because a statue of a nycaloth appears in *Tomb of Annihilation*, which may lead a DM to insert one into the adventure.

Answer (score 8):

### Mezzoloths

There are two Mezzoloths<sup>1</sup> mentioned on page 169 that will leave their tridents behind:

> Opening the wardrobe reveals two mezzoloths, which teleport into the room and attack. When a mezzoloth dies, its body transforms into wisps of oily smoke, **though its trident remains**.

These tridents however are not a magic items. As Thomas mentions in [his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/what-demons-devils-have-trident-attacks/199263#199263) there is no trident in that adventure that causes infernal wounds, so this must be a DM homebrew addition.

As for your title question, **Spined Devils** and [**Horned Devils**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16927-horned-devil) also both wield *forks*, in their images those of spined devils look like a trident, while those of Horned Devils match a bident, but neither is named as a *trident* attack in the stat block, as the mezzoloth's is.

Horned Devils also can cause infernal wounds, albeit with their tails, as can Bearded Devils, and those fight with a *glaive* that is causing infernal wounds. Your DM might have taken inspiration from either them and transferred this feature to a trident. The mechanics of this weapon are described as follows:

> If the target is a creature other than an undead or a construct, it must succeed on a DC 12 Constitution saving throw or lose 5 (1d10) hit points at the start of each of its turns due to an infernal wound. Each time the devil hits the wounded target with this attack, the damage dealt by the wound increases by 5 (1d10). Any creature can take an action to stanch the wound with a successful DC 12 Wisdom (Medicine) check. The wound also closes if the target receives magical healing.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Technically, both the Mezzoloth and the Nycaloth that Thomas mentions in his answer are not demons, they are Yugoloths, or, in older editions "daemons".*